# Overriding Tapestry Grid component column sort icons

Tags: css, tapestry

The default column sort icons in Tapestry Grid components are blue and white. If you have a different color scheme on your page, you'll want to customize this.

What's the best way to override the Tapestry Grid column sort icons with your own custom icons?

I'm using Tapestry 5.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons are defined as constants, you can override them in a contributeApplicationDefaults method in your application's module class (typically AppModule.java) with something like this:

```
  configuration.add(ComponentParameterConstants.GRIDCOLUMNS_ASCENDING_ASSET, "pathtofile");
```

Other two constants are  GRIDCOLUMNS_DESCENDING_ASSET and GRIDCOLUMNS_SORTABLE_ASSET.

Answer (score 2):

I do this with css. I actually hid the sort image all together and used a background image to the header title link. But you can overwrite the default css in any way you want as long as your rules have a higher specificity.

```css
table.t-data-grid thead tr th a img.t-sort-icon {
   display: none !important;
}

table.t-data-grid thead tr th a {
   background-image: url(relative/path/to/your/custom/image.gif);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution too, I'd give it up vote but not enough reputation :(